# Hbase: Flushing regions from client

Tags: hbase

Is there an efficient way of flushing regions from client. I would like to flush all the regions of a table from hbase client.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API [flush()](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#flush%28byte%5B%5D%29) in HBaseAdmin, which flushes a table or an individual region. Synchronous operation, so you need to make sure synchronous is good for your situation.